# Unknown database type enum requested doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am tying to generate entities from an existing database with doctrine in symfony 5 but I keep getting an error its a fresh install of symfony 5.1 and I am using maraidb 10.4.

```
In AbstractPlatform.php line 440:
 Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.
```

the guide i am using `https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html`

Comment: Instead of importing a bad solution, you should perhaps avoid using enum type, you should have a look at http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/ . 
If you really want to use it and if you agreed all problems that they will create, you can create an [EnumType as a custom mapping type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine is not able to reverse engineer the whole model from the database. There are some cases, which can not be handled - like your enums. You will have to define custom types, to tell the doctrine how it have to handle it.

Take a look at this guideline:

-> Scroll to „Solution 2 Defining a Type“

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-1-mapping-to-varchars